# JavaScript logging library which works on node and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, browser

We are currently using Visionmedias debug -library, because it works both on browser and nodejs.

Is there any library which is more robust than debug and works on both ends? At least debug level (error, warn, info etc) is essential. And of course it would be good to have different configurations for browser and server. Our application is isomorphic fluxible/react-aaplication so that's why we need a library which suits for both ends.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel

Log level Library is the best library As far as i know that best suits the requirement.

I works in both front end and server based logging.

And good support for AMD, CommonJS style or normal js script loading.